# Detect Oculus Quest 1 & 2 Headsets in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I'm looking for a way to detect the name of the headset being used in my VR app. I need to distinguish between the **Quest 1 & 2** in order to implement the different controller mappings. Methods like XRDevice.model or OVRPlugin.productName don't provide any name lists in the documentation and since the quest 2 is a new model I haven't found information on it anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running on the Quest 2 directly (as opposed to Oculus Link) you can use

```
OVRPlugin.SystemHeadset headset = OVRPlugin.GetSystemHeadsetType();
if(headset==OVRPlugin.SystemHeadset.Oculus_Quest){
// Quest 1 stuff here
}else if (headset==(OVRPlugin.SystemHeadset.Oculus_Quest+1)){
// Quest 2 stuff here
}
```

They haven't added Oculus Quest 2 to the SystemHeadset enum yet, but it has a "Placeholder_9" in its place.  I just prefer the "+1" for clarity.

If you are using the link, it will return  Oculus_Link_Quest  for Quest 1 and I assume (Oculus_Link_Quest+1) for Quest 2. But I haven't confirmed that.

Edit: As of 2020-12-06, both Quest1 and Quest2 return "Oculus_Link_Quest" if you're using Oculus Link.

Comment: Thank you, that works great! Do you happen to know if the OVRInput touch controller mappings have changed at all from the Quest 1 to 2? I'm assuming they haven't but it seems that the OVRInput documentation hasn't been updated so I'm not totally sure.

Comment: They brought back the "ThumbRest" touch sensor for the Quest2 controllers. ```OVRInput.Touch.PrimaryThumbRest``` It was on the CV1 Touch controllers but not the RiftS or Quest1 Touch controllers.  It's that textured circle next to the face buttons. Technically it was never removed from OVRInput? It's one of those cool hidden features of Oculus Utilities.  (I feel like there are ton of cool features that Oculus is bad about showcasing.)