# Detect Oculus Quest 1 & 2 Headsets in Unity with XR Interaction Toolkit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, quest

I'm looking for a way to detect the name of the headset being used in my VR app. I need to distinguish between the Quest 1 & 2 in order to implement the different controller meshes/skins. I have searched here, this is similar [Detect Oculus Quest 1 & 2 Headsets in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65063797/detect-oculus-quest-1-2-headsets-in-unity) but uses the OVRPlugin which is not available with the XR Interaction Toolkit installed (is it?) Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: or perhaps this?: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo.html

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to check if Quest 2 is tethered or standalone. I did something like this. I am sure you can run it on your Quest 1 device and adjust to do the needful on that device.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class CheckDeviceType : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("operatingSystem: " + SystemInfo.operatingSystem);
        Debug.Log("deviceModel: " + SystemInfo.deviceModel);
        Debug.Log("deviceName: " + SystemInfo.deviceName);
        Debug.Log("deviceType: " + SystemInfo.deviceType);
        Debug.Log("platform: " + Application.platform);

        var devices = new List<InputDevice>();
        InputDevices.GetDevices(devices) ;
        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            Debug.Log("Device connected: " +device.name);
        }

        if (SystemInfo.deviceName == "Oculus Quest 2")
            DoNeededCode(); // Standalone Quest 2
    }
}
```

The output will be like this for Quest 2 standalone in Android Studio Logcat:

```
I/Unity: operatingSystem: Android OS 10 / API-29 (QQ3A.200805.001/19130100154900000)
I/Unity: deviceModel: Oculus Quest
I/Unity: deviceName: Oculus Quest 2
I/Unity: deviceType: Handheld
I/Unity: platform: Android
I/Unity: Device connected: Oculus Quest
I/Unity: Device connected: Oculus Touch Controller - Left
I/Unity: Device connected: Oculus Touch Controller - Right
```

And like this in Unity Editor on Windows:

[image]